# How to run BrowserStackLocal for website behind firewall

Tags: browserstack

I'm trying to run my tests against a url that is behind our firewall.

I run this command:

```
./BrowserStackLocal [KEY] -force &
```

And then I run my tests:

```
py.test blah blah
```

In BrowserStack I see this error:

[image]

I must be doing something wrong when running the BrowserStackLocal binary, but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the local servers on BrowserStack Automate, you can follow these steps:

1. Setup the Local Testing connection by executing the Local Testing binaries.
2. Add the capability `'browserstack.local' = true` in your scripts.

It seems you have done Step 1, have you added the capability as well?

Comment: Correct, not only did I have to use browserstack.local=true, but I also had to use v4.2.  I set the value to true, but it was still failing, but when i upgraded to v4.2 of the binary, it started working. (This was on a linux 64 bit)  Thanks!

Comment: After running for a few days, it just started failing again. It turns out the binary has changed yet again on https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing  Too bad 1) there is no version history of the binaries on that webpage 2) binaries are not backwards compatible 3) no error from the binary when you try to run an older version. ARGH

Answer (score 0):

**Few things to consider here :**

1. Are you setting correct Host settings .
2. Have you tried with multiple browser versions because I get some errors while trying for IE and chrome for Android devices.

**Please try to use the below simple code and check :**

```
   public static final String USERNAME = "xyz";
   public static final String AUTOMATE_KEY = "xyz";
   public static final String URL = "http://" + USERNAME + ":" + AUTOMATE_KEY + "@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
          DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
          System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
          System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","2.2.2.2");
          System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","8080");
          System.setProperty("http.proxyUser","xyz");
          System.setProperty("http.proxyPass","xyz");
          caps.setCapability("browser", "FireFox");
          caps.setCapability("browser_version", "40.0");
          caps.setCapability("os", "Windows");
          caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
          caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true"); 
          WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
          driver.get("http://www.google.com");
          WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
          element.sendKeys("BrowserStack");
          element.submit();
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
          driver.quit();
   }
```